# Composing text string dependant on if column in csv contains data

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, append, match

I have a csv which contains a large dataset, now what I need to be able to do is compose tesxt strings based on if a column contains data. For instance if column 30 contains data then compose a text string: "Text data text (row[30]) texy data text (row[12]) text data text" and append to a new file.

```
X,classA,uniqueclassindicator1,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classA,uniqueclassindicator1,x,x,3,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classB,uniqueclassindicator2,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,7/9,2.05,£12.02
X,classB,uniqueclassindicator2,x,x,2,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classB,uniqueclassindicator2,x,x,3,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classB,uniqueclassindicator2,x,x,4,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classA,uniqueclassindicator3,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classA,uniqueclassindicator3,x,x,2,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classA,uniqueclassindicator3,x,x,3,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classA,uniqueclassindicator3,x,x,4,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classC,uniqueclassindicator4,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classC,uniqueclassindicator4,x,x,2,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classC,uniqueclassindicator4,x,x,3,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classC,uniqueclassindicator4,x,x,4,x,x,x,x,125,30.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classC,uniqueclassindicator4,x,x,5,x,x,x,x,125,31.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classC,uniqueclassindicator4,x,x,6,x,x,x,x,125,2130.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classA,uniqueclassindicator5,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,125,35.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,95/100,,£15.06
X,classA,uniqueclassindicator5,x,x,2,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classA,uniqueclassindicator5,x,x,3,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classA,uniqueclassindicator5,x,x,4,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classA,uniqueclassindicator5,x,x,5,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
X,classA,uniqueclassindicator5,x,x,6,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,
```

As part of the same script I need to be able to perform the same thing for column 31 & 32.

For instance the output file for column 30 only would read:

```
Text data text 7/9 texy data text 21.8 text data text
Text data text 95/100 texy data text 21.8 text data text
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards SMNALLY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, very similar to the above but opens a csv file:

#### Code:

```
import csv

with open(test.csv', 'rb') as mycsv:

    for item in mycsv:
        item = item.split(',')
        if item[29]:
            print ("Data text data %s" % (item[29])
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a string list, one item each line.

```
a = ['X,classA,uniqueclassindicator1,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,',
     'X,classA,uniqueclassindicator1,x,x,3,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,,',
     'X,classB,uniqueclassindicator2,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,125,21.8,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,7/9,2.05,\xc2\xa312.02',
     .....
    ]
for item in a:
    item = item.split(',')
    if item[29]:
        print ('Text data text %s texy data text %s text data text' % (item[29], item[11]))
```